# How to convert a text file with mixture of encodings to a single encoding?

Tags: gedit, emacs, encoding

1. I created a text file by copying its different parts from different
   sources (webpages, other text files, pdf files) into gedit and
   saving it to the file. I guess that is the reason that I have
   multiple encodings in the text file, but I am not sure.  How can I
   avoid creating a text file with mixed encodings by copying its
   different parts from different sources into gedit?
2. Whenever I open the file in gedit, gedit can always show or decode
   every part of the text correctly. It seems that gedit can handle a
   text file with mixed encodings, but I am not sure.

   But when I open the file in emacs, there will be characters that
   can't be shown correctly. (I am not sure why emacs can't do that.)
   So I would like to convert the file from mixed encodings to a single
   encoding such as utf-8.

   Since I think gedit can detect the correct encodings for different parts of the text file, and I don't know if there are other applications that can do so, would it be possible to ask gedit to convert the file to
   utf-8, or at least tell me what encoding it finds for which part of the file?

Thanks.

Comment: When you click `File > Save As`, you should see two options on the bottom of the window, one for character encoding, and second for line endings.

Comment: Is that the encoding which gedit used  for opening the text file?

Comment: Most probably it is.

Comment: Is that also the encoding which gedit guessed for the text file?

Comment: I guess so. When you open a file you can also choose an encoding to use, or you can let it auto detect the encoding.

Comment: Yet, `file->Save as` only shows one encoding. I think the text file has a mixture of encodings: different encoding for different part of the file. (See my first part.) So should there be multiple encodings, each for different part?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17473/discussion-between-jeremija-and-tim).

Comment: I had the same problem and solved it with Emacs. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18311399/emacs-displays-chinese-character-if-i-open-xml-file)

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm... the concept of a file with various encoding is somewhat wobbly, to be honest. If you have a bit of time, [this article](http://blog.codinghorror.com/there-aint-no-such-thing-as-plain-text/) (and [this one](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)) are worth reading.

For Linux a file is a sequence of bytes. If you ask a program to interpret it as a text file, it will do it using a mapping between bytes and characters; this mapping is the encoding. Almost all the text editor I know (not word processors!) just understand the concept of one encoding for one file.

I am not expert on `gedit`; maybe it is doing some magic like trying to autodetect the encoding line by line or text block by text block... if it is the case you can try to do the same using [`enca`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/enca)(1):

```
 while read line; do echo $line | enconv -L none -x utf8; done < text.mixed > text.utf8
```

...but it depends on how good is enca in guessing you encoding (works almost well with Eastern European, but not with Latin1, for example).

(1) It's in the repos, just install it with `sudo apt-get enca`.

Comment: (1) But I may be wrong. I get the impression of mixed encodings from using tools such as chardet to detect the mixed encodings for the file, and from failing to convert all of the text file to another encoding by specifying only one original encoding. (2) Generally, if you copy texts from different sources possibly with different encodings to a gedit window, and save it to a file, will gedit save it with just one encoding? Which encoding does gedit use for saving? Does that involve conversion from the sources' encodings to the file's encoding?

Comment: I do not know if the copy/paste protocol has the possibility to send the encoding together with the data, and if all the copy sources send it. I fear not, but I could be wrong. So probably there is a guessing wrong here. I know for sure that copy and paste between different encoding seldom works.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved it with Emacs. The solution is quoted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18311399/emacs-displays-chinese-character-if-i-open-xml-file):

> Another possible solution is to mark each region appearing with Chinese characters and recode it with M-x recode-region, giving "Text was really in" as utf-16-le and "But was interpreted as" as utf-16-be.

Another one is to split the two parts which have different encodings, copy them into different files, convert the encoding of the one and add it to the other. In my case this worked with Atom, but not with Notepad++ (utf16-le/be).